# PluginPackager exited with code 99

Tags: ocean, petrel

Using the ocean wizard I have generated a pip project and am now trying to build it after adding things to the DeployList.xml.  However I then get the following message:
The command

> ""%OCEAN2013HOME%\PluginPackager.exe" /p
>   "C:\ext_source\ext_6_1_2013\ocean\IkonRockPhysicsWorkflowPIP2013\obj\copytemp\IkonSyntheticsPlugin.dll"
>   "C:\ext_source\ext_6_1_2013\ocean\x64\Release\IkonRockPhysicsWorkflowPIP2013.pip""
>   exited with code 99.

Does anybody know what this code means and how to fix it?  The other pip project builds just fine and includes exactly the same contents except for two dll's.  Removing these two dll's still does not work.

Comment: If you find the actual PluginPackager call in the build output, is there any additional information there?  99 is just a default ERROR status from PluginPackager.exe rather than an indicator of a specific problem.  The actual output from the command is typically more useful.  For example, if the .dll isn't found in the specified location, the Error list will simply show "exited with code 99" but the build output will say "Foo.dll could not be found."

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is due to one of the following:

- The PIP file does not contain a `public Plugin` class
- You have more than one `Plugin` class in your PIP
- Your assemblies are referencing the wrong Petrel public assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Another issue might be because of the reference "Slb.Ocean.Data" "Copy Local" property is set to "True". This property should set "False"

Answer (score 0):

Also it could be if you use Petrel 32-bit, while %OCEAN2013HOME% refers to 64-bit version (and vice versa).